# Which container is typically used for the loading of new custom components into Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash

In an AIR application, I have a link button for winner statistics. If I click this button, then the statistics  are shown on a full page (Canvas) in my application. I have already created the statistics using the Canvas component. Which container is typically used for viewing such data?
Any references?  I tried a ViewStack, but will it overwrite the Main page?

Answer (score 0):

Could you give some more information? If you are trying to show tabulated data, you can try a DataGrid. If you have a component you would like to list, then a VBox would work and you could just add your winner stats component to the list.

Comment: I used Canves component(Winner statistics) . within canves More components there like Show data, hide data,Chat and etc . Then In my application have winner statistics (button) if i click this button h
how can i load Winner statistics (Canves) into Main application ? . Do you understand what i say ? itried more ways but not get